# Alternative to save in JPA/Hibernate with non autogenerated ID

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to insert a value into a database with type String in ID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xpto_version_map")
public class XptoVersionMap implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name =  "uniq_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String uniq_name;
...
```

When trying to save a new XptoVersionMap() like:

```
XptoVersionMap xptoVersionMap = new XptoVersionMap();
xptoVersionMap.setUniqName("XPTO-1");
xptoVersionMap.setValue("value2");

xptoVersionMapRepository.save(xptoVersionMap);
```

Will throw:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find xxx.api.database.entity.XptoVersionMap with id XPTO-1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find xxx.api.database.entity.XptoVersionMap with id XPTO-1.
```

I've tried different solutions, but unless I can make a native query to insert the value, I can't have a way to tell Hibernate that I want to just check if the @Id (uniq_name) exists, if not insert the new value and not to throw an exception.

Comment: Are you sure it is in the save that throws exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Hibernate works by default. It assigns an automated generated ID when you do save method and ID is not set. If there is an ID it tries to update it (what happens in your case).

> **save** Persists an entity. Will assign an identifier if one doesn't
>   exist. If one does, it's essentially doing an update. Returns the
>   generated ID of the entity.

You can do a workaround for example by using persist and @PrePersist

```
@PrePersist
void generateId() {
    if (uniq_name == null) {
        uniq_name = GENERATE_SOME_UNIQUE_ID_SO_IT_DOESN'T_BREAK();
    }
}
```

And then use xptoVersionMapRepository.persist(xptoVersionMap);

Or you can write your own generator with something like that:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "my_generator", strategy = "package.CustomGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "my_generator")
```

And then create a class CustomGenerator that implements IdentifierGenerator and create the required methods.

Comment: Thanks, I've saw @PrePersist but didn't understand that needed to use persist(). I will try it.

Comment: I believe writing a custom generator is the better way to do it. Otherwise you will end up with some objects that have proper IDs and some that don't

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to generate nothing, I know the value that I want to add. I need to find some way to pass the value that I want to add if I want to setup like a custom generator.

Comment: Check that blog https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/

Comment: In the custom generator presented there he checks if the Object already has an ID and then just uses that ID

Comment: A more canonical solution to this problem would be to implement `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` and override `isNew`

Comment: I finally made it work. Persist method isn't available on the Repository, so I needed to use EntityManager.