# How to save without using autogenerated in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using oracle database with JPA, I have an id column this is not auto generated type.
While performing saveAll() operation we are getting - ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():
This is Id i am getting form some other table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "area_usr")
public class AreaUsr {

    @Id
    private Integer usrId;
    private String area;
    //getter setter
}
```

```
List<AreaUsr> au = xyzRepo.getAreaInfo();
areaUsrRepo.saveAll(au); // here i am getting the error
```

Comment: Perhaps you look at this answer ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156344/alternative-to-save-in-jpa-hibernate-with-non-autogenerated-id

Answer (score 0):

Because ids can't be null ,and since it's not auto generated ,it must be specified before getting persisted.